# Error when linking shared library after compiling objects

Tags: c++, gcc, shared-libraries

I compiled the object files, and then tried to compile the executable, which failed by saying that there are undefined references to functions in "theLib".

```
g++ -I./theLib/src -c -o obj/main.o src/main.cpp
```

(works so far)

```
g++ -L./theLib -Wl,-rpath=./theLib obj/main.o -ltheLib -o exe
```

(error: `libtheLib.so: undefined reference to 'some_function'`)

I checked for answers everywhere, and they all just suggest moving the `-ltheLib` part after the dependencies (which I did). But it still doesn't work. What really boggles my mind is that the same library compiles just fine for an example in a different directory.

The library is in C. Can that mess up trying to compile C++? Or am I just missing something with compiling the `.o` files first?

Comment: Do you use `extern "C"` for functions from `theLib` which you are using in C++ code?

Comment: The library headers do includes this, yes.

Comment: It's not unusual for libraries to reference (parts of) other libraries. You likely need to find out the dependencies for theLib and add them to your linker commandline.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the library depended on functions that I had to implement and provide in my own source code. I never knew that some libraries did that, but lesson learned. Once I implemented the functions that were causing the errors and added those source files, it worked.